# How to parse xml in golang with list of multiple elements values. And store them in list

Tags: xml, parsing, go

I want to parse this xml and store in one data structure in golang below.

camera: LibX,LibY,...(dynamic list)
display: LibP,LibQ,...(dynamic list)

```
 <techpackages>
    <techpackage>
        <techpackage_name> camera </techpackage_name>
        <library>LibX</library>
        <library>LibY</library>
        ....(dynamic number of libraries)
    </techpackage>
    <techpackage>
        <techpackage_name> display </techpackage_name>
        <library>LibP</library>
        <library>LibQ</library>
        ....(dynamic number of  libraries)
    </techpackage>
</techpackages>
```

Comment: What is the Go struct you want in the end?

Comment: look at encoding/xml

Comment: @BurakSerdar I want to parse in Go language. Thats why I have mentioned Go structure which can store the data in above mentioned format

Comment: That is not a Go structure. Is that an array? A struct? Define the output you want as a go structure first. Then, if possible, you can add XML tags to that struct to unmarshal the input. If it is not possible, you can use an intermediate struct matching the input structure to unmarshal, and then process to make it look like what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unmarshal what you call "dynamic list" into a slice.

```
type TechPackages struct {
    xml.Name    `xml:"techpackages"`
    TechPackage []TechPackage `xml:"techpackage"`
}

type TechPackage struct {
    TechPackageName string   `xml:"techpackage_name"`
    Library         []string `xml:"library"`
}

var pp TechPackages
if err := xml.Unmarshal(data, &pp); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/T0shyWsBAFg